# Как данные из одного input вывести в другой input

Tags: javascript, input

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Дано два инпута, в одном календарь и при выборе даты в другом должно отразиться кол.во дней до определенной даты(2019-09-28). Через консоль все получается, но не могу сделать чтобы во втором инпуте выводилось

```
<label for="date">Дата</label> 
<input id="date" type ="date" name="date" value ="">
<label for="dates">Колличество дней</label>
<input id="dates" type ="dates" name="dates" value ="" disabled="">


date.addEventListener('click', getDayDiff);

function getDayDiff()
{
let date1 = document.getElementById('date').valueAsNumber;
let date2 = new Date("2019-09-28");
 console.log(date2);
console.log( Math.floor((date2 - date1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) ));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У атрибута *type* не бывает значения *dates*.

```js
date.addEventListener('input', getDayDiff);

function getDayDiff() {
  let date1 = date.valueAsNumber;
  let date2 = new Date("2019-09-28");
  dates.value = Math.abs((date2 - date1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
}
```

```html
<label for="date">Дата</label>
<input id="date" type="date" name="date" value="">
<label for="dates">Колличество дней</label>
<input id="dates" type="text" name="dates" value="" disabled="">
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает!!!

Comment: Действительно у меня тоже работает!